# Can't use JFXDatePicker in scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to add JFXDatePicker to a form in JavaFX scene builder by drag and drop
but when I want to drop it it didn't added also I tried to add it to the Hierarchy
and the same result.

Any Help.

Comment: Show some code/Image to explain the problem better.

Comment: Have you been trying to add it directly to the code and did it work in that case?

Comment: `JFXDatePicker` is from third party Jfoenix isn't it? did you [import the jfoenix jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25612769/6242846) in scene builder?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>`.
And make sure you using Java FX8?

Answer (score 0):

You need add next configuration to your **scene builder** (file: *C:\Users\my_windows_user\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\app\SceneBuilder.cfg*).

```
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix

java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.beans=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED

java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.beans=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=com.jfoenix
```

I had the same problem when I migrated a project, but currently JFoenix it's too broken (and it has not support) to recommend use it.